# Make a layout in drawable that has 3 borders of same color and one is different

Tags: android

Actually I made a drawable resource file for the background of my layout. I want that my layout should have 3 sides of same color and one side of different color.

In this piece of code, all sides of layout has red color. I want 3 should have red color and one should have white color.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <stroke  android:color="@color/colorLightRed" android:width="1dp">

    </stroke>
</shape>
```

Comment: Create a `Layer-List` drawable ..

Comment: i don't about it . can u help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this . Its not the best solution i guess ..

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:right="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
        <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/black30">
        </stroke>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
        <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/green">

        </stroke>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: thanks for help but here is a problem i need right border to be different from rest of three in your answer it is left border

Comment: Its only matter of attributes . use the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Layer list in order to do that.Add your colors for Bottom,Top,Left and for right side.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <!-- Set the border color of your layout here -->
                <solid android:color="#3AFB03" />

            </shape>
        </item>

        <!-- This is for border bottom but
        you can change this according to your need -->
        <item android:right="4dp" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <!-- Set the background color of your layout here -->
                <solid android:color="#000000" />
            </shape>
        </item>


   <item android:left="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFEB3B"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00BCD4" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFF00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#4CAF50" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00BCD4" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]